# Laravel 7.28 not work without php artisan serve command in localhost

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Laravel 7.28 not work without php artisan serve command in localhost

I install new  Laravel in localhost (/var/www/html/NewLaravel)

When I run  `http://localhost/NewLaravel/public/` not workling

but when I run with `php artisan serve` its working on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Apache2 is working proper and allow access of override for `.htaccess`

is that new Laravel will only work with `php artisan serve` ?? or something is missing from my side ?

Comment: its on your side, you don't have your webserver configured correctly apparently ... also what is "not working"? what do you expect to happen and what is actually happening

Comment: It is very easy to implement as your expectation. All files in public folder `cut` and `paste` outside of public folder. then localhost works fine

Answer (score 0):

**Step-1:**

run apache and sql from xampp server

**step-2:**

in browser type localhost/NewLaravel and press enter

**Step-3:**

in list please select public folder it will run